# Normal subgroups index$[G:H]$ = prime number

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

The question states: Let $G$ be a group and let $H$ be a normal subgroup of $G$. Assume that index$[G:H] = p$ is a prime number. Let $a \in G$, but $a \notin H$, and prove that $a^p \in H$ and $a^m \notin H$, for $m=1,2,\dots,p-1$.

What I have so far:

Let $k=$ord$(Ha)$, with $Ha \in G/H$. This implies $(Ha)^k=e$ and this implies $H(a^k)=e$. Now, if $m=kq$

$(Ha)^{kq}=e$ implies $(Ha)^m=e$.

If $(Ha)^m=e$, then $m$ is a multiple of ord$(Ha)$ and ord$(Ha)$ is a divisor of $m$, so $(Ha)^m =H(a^m)=e$

Let $|G|=p$ (prime). If $a \in G$ and $ a\neq e$, then ord$(a)=m(\neq 1)$ and $\langle a \rangle=(a_1 a_2 a_3 \dots a_{m-1})$, so $m$ must be a factor of $p$, but $p$ is prime, so $m=p$.

Am I even close to the correct answer?

Comment: For a basic tutorial on how to use Latex code to type Math on this page, see http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference. It would improve the readability of your question.

Comment: I edited this, did not alter anything of the sloppy way this is written down. E.g. your $e$ must be $H$ when you are making calculations in $G/H$. So user105108, please try to improve and learn some Latex on the side through my editing!

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**: What can you say about cyclic subgroups of a group with $p$ elements (like $G/H$)?